# Spring Boot REST controller not returning HTML string

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that has one controller that serves mostly RESTful endpoints, but it has 1 endpoint that actually needs to return HTML.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/data/accounts")
public class AccountResource {
    // Half a dozen endpoints that are all pure data, RESTful APIs

    @GetMapping("/confirmRegistration")
    public void confirmRegistration(@RequestParam(value = "vt") String token) {
        // Some logic goes here

        System.out.println("This should work!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok('<HTML><body>Hey you did a good job!.</body></HTML>')
    }
}
```

When this runs, no errors/exceptions get thrown at all, and in fact I see the "*This should work!*" log message in my app logs. However from both a browser and a curl command, the HTTP response is empty. Any idea what I need to change in the `ResponEntity` builder to get the server returning a hand-crafted HTML string?

Comment: Can you please post a proper [mcve]? The code above has a `void` return type, so it doesn't return anything, besides that it has a string with single quotes. Also make sure that the `// Some logic goes here` doesn't cause the error. Returning a HTML string like that however should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `@RequestMapping` or `@GetMapping`

```
 produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE
```

Spring defaults to `application\json`. If you need any other type, you need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran (+1) - however this causes my app to throw an exception due to missing `ViewResolvers`. I think specifying `MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE` prompts Spring to try and start doing magic under the hood to look up a view/template file to return. Is there no other way of telling Spring to just blindly return a specify string (regardless of whether it has HTML in it or not)? Thanks again!

Comment: you should have a proper Accept header set in your app